# How substitutable is Statistics for Mathematics in graduate admissions?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states

In some undergraduate programs, "Statistics" courses (including probability) are listed under the "Math" department. In others, they are "cross listed" with Math courses. And in some others, they are listed as entirely separate disciplines.

Switch over to the admissions department of an American graduate school, with distinctly separate Math and Statistics departments. The informal requirement for admission to the Math graduate program is ten Math courses. But a particular candidate (yours truly, perhaps), has "only" eight math courses, but two statistics courses also. If you treat those as "math" courses, the candidate has ten. The relevant GPA is 3.5; four A's and four B's in Math; one A and one B in Stat. The candidate's GRE score is about 60th percentile for your program; letters of recommendation are solid, but not outstanding.

How might various American graduate programs look upon an application where two statistics courses "replaced" two math courses? Suppose it was four statistics courses; two As and two Bs? People in your school believe that Statistics is "soft" Math, but in the latter case, the candidate has two "extra" courses, FWIW, and maybe some extra preparation and demonstration of dedication.

Comment: Pure or applied math? Not a mathematician so I can't make any definitive statements, but my first thought would be that it wouldn't fly for pure math but might work for applied math depending on the concentration area.

Comment: Best to ask the admissions department and, they would,if necessary, contact the relevant professors to check. The professors can then decide.

Answer (score 0):

This can only be answered by the university in question, probably at the level of the math department. It might depend on the specific statistics courses that you want math credit for. As you say, statistics overlaps with math a fair amount and many of the courses depend on a mathematical outlook and way of thinking.

In general, though, I think you are more likely to have them accepted than rejected, but you still have to face the fact that there will be a lot of other applicants for whom no exceptions need be made. So in a competitive place it might be the competition with those having a more standard background that will work against you.

But you have to ask them, and, as usual, you need to make your own case for why you will be a success. The evaluation depends on many things not just a bit of bookkeeping.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering based on a "compendium" of comments on my earlier post, and elsewhere.

First of all, the substitution of statistics for math courses is more likely to be acceptable in an applied, rather than pure, math program. Statistics can be considered "applied," math.

Second, role-playing the admissions officer at a graduate "pure" math program, I would look at the type and quality of the of the undergraduate math courses, rather than just their sheer number. I can think of three distinct cases for the eight math course program.

Case 1: The "eight" math courses consist of 12 credits of calculus (either three courses of four credits or four courses of three), two "foundation" (proofs) courses, plus linear algebra, and differential equations. These are all "intermediate" courses, and there are no "advanced" courses in real or complex analysis, number theory, abstract algebra, etc. This is the least likely to be acceptable.

Case 2: They eight math courses consist of three courses (9 credits) of calculus, one course (three or four credits) of linear algebra/differential equations, plus real analysis, complex analysis,  number theory and abstract algebra, or four "advanced" courses. This is most likely to be acceptable, with or without the stat courses.

Case 3: The eight math courses include nine credits of calculus, nine of intermediate math (linear algebra, differential equations, "foundations") and two of the following: real analysis, complex analysis, abstract algebra, number theory, etc. This is an "intermediate" case, where the statistics courses might make a difference:

Case 3a: One course in probability and one course in statistics. These are "intermediate" courses that don't add much to the case of two advanced courses.

Case 3b: *Four* courses in probability and statistics. Let's say that they are Probability I and II and Statistics I and II. The II-level courses include elements of combinatorics and logic, "advanced" level courses. As an admissions officer, I would likely give credit for three, or even four, advanced math courses.

Different graduate schools will have different acceptance criteria of course. Some will accept all of the above, others will accept none of the above, and some will accept "some" of the above. But perhaps placing the various types of background on a continuum is helpful.

Comment: You answered your own question?  

Comment: @JalapenoNachos: The site gives a "self learned" badge for people who ask a question and answer it with a score of plus 2 or better. In this case, I drew inspiration from the comments and other answer, and also from people I talked to off site. I did not "know" the answer when I first asked the question, but I "found out" later. You can see the influence of others in my answer.That's why I called it a "compendium" of other sources.